# How to write elasticsearch query aggregation in java?

Tags: java, elasticsearch, aggregation, sense

This is my code in Marvel Sense:

```
GET /sweet/cake/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {"term": {
          "code":"18"
        }}
      ]
    }
  },
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "group_by_state": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "id"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And I want to write it in Java but I dont't know how.

Comment: What version of Elasticsearch are you running?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find some examples in the [official documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/index.html) for the Java client.

But in your case, you need to create one `bool/must` query using the `QueryBuilders` and one `terms` aggregation using the `AggregationBuilders`. It goes like this:

```
// build the query
BoolQueryBuilder query = QueryBuilders.boolFilter()
    .must(QueryBuilders.termFilter("code", "18"));

// build the terms sub-aggregation
TermsAggregation stateAgg = AggregationBuilders.terms("group_by_state")
    .field("id");

SearchResponse resp = client.prepareSearch("sweet")
        .setType("cake")
        .setQuery(query)
        .setSize(0)
        .addAggregation(stateAgg)
        .execute()
        .actionGet();
```